# Laravel Model Relationship with Where & orWhere Statement

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following in my controller:

```
            $documents = $equipment->attachments()
                ->where('attachmentCategory','=','Document')
                ->orWhere('attachmentCategory','=','Vehicle Title')
                ->get();
```

But while the documents with `attachmentCategory` that are equal to `Document` return fine, it proceeds to bring in ALL documents with the `Vehicle Title` attachmentCategory, even though if I try this statement with just the where and it being `Vehicle Title` it will only return one document (which is correct).

This is my relationship as defined in my function, and this has not failed me anywhere else, so I do know it's in the above controller statement, I am just putting this here just in case.

```
public function attachments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(EquipmentAttachment::class,'unitID','id');
}
```

If you could correct the statement above, that would be great. I would like it to return documents to me only if they have an attachmentCategory of `Document` OR `Vehicle Title`.

Comment: Can confirm that same happens to me. Probably not the expected behaviour and seems like a bug. The solution I posted works though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like that might be a Laravel bug. I'll test it out.

This is the solution though:

```
$documents = $equipment->attachments()
    ->where(function ($q) {
        $q
            ->where('attachmentCategory','=','Document')
            ->orWhere('attachmentCategory','=','Vehicle Title');
    })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

*I would like it to return documents to me only if they have an attachmentCategory of Document OR Vehicle Title.*

From above i assume you need to apply filter on related collection, If it matches the given criteria then return main object like [Querying Relationship Existence](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships)

```
$documents = $equipment->whereHas('attachments', function ($query) {
                            $query->whereIn('attachmentCategory', ['Document', 'Vehicle Title']);
                        })
                        ->get();
```